# Do I need to quarantine in Colombia if I have a negative Covid test?

Tags: covid-19, colombia, quarantine

Colombia does require a negative Covid test for entry. If it's impossible for you to take one they allow getting one in Colombia and quarantine until the results are in.

However, I have not found any mentioning of quarantine  requirements (positive or negative) if you already have the test on entry.

The US embassy states [https://co.usembassy.gov/covid-19-information/#:~:text=Quarantine%20Information](https://co.usembassy.gov/covid-19-information/#:%7E:text=Quarantine%20Information)

> Are U.S. citizens required to quarantine?  Yes.

But it's unclear whether this is a general requirement or only related to lack of testing.

Any other resource I found doesn't mention quarantine or only in context of "no test". However, I haven't seen anything that specifically states: "No quarantine required if you have a negative test".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.